# What is the right way to print fibonacci sequence in python

Tags: python

```
def fibonacci(n):
 a = 0
 b = 1
 for i in range(n):
  a=b
  b=a+b
  print(a,end = " ")

fibonacci(10)

Result = 1 2 4 8 16 32 64 128 256 512
```

Why i am getting two different results ? what makes the python to print 2 different outputs.Currently i am using python 3

```
def fibonacci(n):
 a,b = 0,1
 for i in range(n):
  a,b=b,a+b
  print(a,end = " ")

fibonacci(10)

Result = 1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55

Why i am getting two different results ? what makes the python to print 2 different outputs.Currently i am using python 3.
```

Comment: In the first examp!e you are changing the value of a before adding it with b.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one always try to update a with b, and next one makes b as 2b

The second performs all updates at once so you should be able to execute it fine. Instead to have a first method, you can go as follows

```
 for i in range(n):
  print(b)
  b=a+b
  a=b-a
```

Answer (score 1):

The difference is how you do the sum:

```
a=b
b=a+b
```

versus

```
a,b=b,a+b
```

The first one sets `a` to `b`. So by the time `a+b` is calculated, it actually becomes `b+b` or `2*b` which is why you see the doubling sequence.

The second method of doing the sum adds up and updates everything all at once.

Answer (score 0):

the first one you need another variable as intermediate.
in python

```
a,b = b, a+b  is equal to 
c = b
b = a +b 
a = c
```

Answer (score 0):

Each iteration needs to update `a` and `b` as follows:

```
new_a = old_b
new_b = old_a + old_b
```

But you have to be careful not to reassign one of the variables from the old iteration before using it for the values of the new iteration.  For example:

```
a = b
b = a + b
```

This properly updates `a`, but now the old value of `a` is no longer available, and `b` ends up getting `new_a` + `old_b`, which is the same as `old_b` + `old_b`.  So it doesn't work.  Similarly, you can't update `b` before `a` because then the old value of `b` will no longer be available.

One solution is to use a temporary variable to hold the old value of a:

```
t = a
a = b
b = t + b
```

Another solution, which you're using, is to update both values simultaneously:

```
a,b = b,a+b
```

This first captures the values of `b` and `a+b` before anything has been changed.  It then assigns those values to `a` and `b`.